# ending call in android using telephonyserivce.endcall()

Tags: android, telephony, telephonymanager

I am working on app where i want to end outgoing call.
this is the main class

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class phonecalls extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    call();
}

private void call() {
try {
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
    startActivity(callIntent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityException) {
    Log.e("dialing-example", "Call failed", activityException);
}
}
}
```

and outgoingclass is this

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class OutgoingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private final String TAG = "CallControl";
Context context;
String incomingNumber;
ITelephony telephonyService;  

@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    try {
        // Java reflection to gain access to TelephonyManager's
        // ITelephony getter
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        if(null == bundle)
                return;

        String phonenumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

        Log.i("OutgoingCallReceiver",phonenumber);
        Log.i("OutgoingCallReceiver",bundle.toString());

        String info = "Detect Calls sample application\nOutgoing number: " + phonenumber;


        Toast.makeText(context, info, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Log.v(TAG, "Get getTeleService...");
        Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        telephonyService=(ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);
        telephonyService.endCall();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG,
                "FATAL ERROR: could not connect to telephony subsystem");
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception object: " + e);
    }       

    }
}
```

But the call is not ended even though i am able to print no. when outgoing call starts which show broadcasting receiver is working right .

Any suggestion

Comment: Finally Done, so anybody need help in this can ask.. happy to help

Comment: Can you help me I need a working version of ending a call from a particular number using any technique. I need a working version on 2.3.3+ Device can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes definately there is two way to do it either using airplane mode or internal telephony for this . I used internal telephony and code I developed is uploaded here https://github.com/deependersingla/end_calls.

If you need anything more tell me , will be happy to help.

Comment: @ deepender Singla the code you uploaded on your github does that project blocks the incoming call or Outgoing calls Can you explain it And can you also explain in which format we have to give the number for call blocking means if the number which I want to block is 0345xxxxxxx should I just pass it to like this into the intent or  I enter the number like this 92345XXXXXXX Can you explain ?

Comment: this project does not block any number it just end the call after few seconds , it gives missed call of specified seconds .