# How do I abort a call and close the dialer after launching my activity?

Tags: android, telephony, telephonymanager

As I can remember it, Avast anti-theft lets you set up a "secret pin" that you can dial in order to open up the UI. What happens when I dial it is that **the call doesn't go through**, then the dialer closes immediately and the UI opens up (or the UI goes above the dialer activity. I forgot).

I somehow implemented this, but instead of the call aborting, it goes to the background (green statusbar, ringing phone, etc.) while my activity goes in front of it.

How do I abort the call while opening up my own activity when I dial a specific number?

Some code on my approach:

Broadcast receiver for calls:

```
public class OutgoingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Match if action is outgoing call.

            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setAction(HelperClass.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOINGCALL);
            i.setClassName(HelperClass.PACKAGE_NAME, HelperClass.CLASS_NAME_OUTGOING);
            i.putExtra(HelperClass.CONTACT_KEY, "contact");
            i.putExtra(HelperClass.CLIENT_DEVICE_KEY, "DUMMY");
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            startActivity(i);

            // Apparently, this doesn't work
            abortBroadcast();





// --------------- FAILED ATTEMPT ---------------------

//        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {
//            TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context
//                    .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
//            try {
//                // Java reflection to gain access to TelephonyManager's
//                // ITelephony getter
//                Log.v(HelperClass.TAG, "Get getTeleService...");
//                Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
//                Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
//                m.setAccessible(true);
//                com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony telephonyService =
//                        (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);
//            } catch (Exception e) {
//                e.printStackTrace();
//                Log.e(TAG,
//                        "FATAL ERROR: could not connect to telephony subsystem");
//                Log.e(TAG, "Exception object: " + e);
//            }
        }
    }
}
```

Failed attempt: ITelephony not found. The failed attempt came from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5314372/3979290

UPDATE: Tried to implement, failed. Not sure how to implement: [How to hang up outgoing call in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/599443/3979290)

Also viewed: [How to abort an outgoing call after fixed seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14066574/3979290)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: Adding `setResultData(null);` to the broadcast receiver worked.
It immediately ended the call.

Sample:

```
public class OutgoingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Immediately cancels the call since this sets the number to null.
        setResultData(null);

        // Launch activity here/other stuff you want to do
        // Example:
        //     Intent i = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
        //     i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        //     context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
...
        <receiver
            android:name=".OutgoingCallReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
...
```